# putty(vt100+ mode) + screen + emacs = no num keypad?

Tags: emacs, putty, gnu-screen

Putty (VT100+) mode
GNU screen
emacs

The keys on the numkeypad no longer work. Is there any easy way to fix this?
(I'm not familiar with customizing emacs settings, and prefer not to mess with .emacs if at all possible. If inevitable, I can go that route too)

emacs-new c-Q informs that number 4 and 6 (with numlock on) on the numpad produce: `^[Ot ^[Ov`